# Как проверить атрибут на заполненость при помощи jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят, как можно проверить атрибут data-name= у нескольких class на наличие заполнености и если атрибут data-name= окажется пустым, то добавить class с именем hide?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589558/jquery-to-check-if-returned-data-object-is-empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант на JS

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.test').forEach(function(elem) {
  if(!elem.dataset.name || elem.dataset.name.length === 0) elem.classList.add('hide')
});
```

```css
.hide {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<b>Проверка дата атрибутов:</b>
<div class="test" data-name="123">Есть</div>
<div class="test" data-name="">Есть, но пустой</div>
<div class="test">Отсутствует</div>
```

И на JQ

```js
$('.test').each(function() {
  if(!$(this).attr('data-name') || $(this).attr('data-name').length === 0) $(this).addClass('hide')
});
```

```css
.hide {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<b>Проверка дата атрибутов:</b>
<div class="test" data-name="123">Есть</div>
<div class="test" data-name="">Есть, но пустой</div>
<div class="test">Отсутствует</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за оба варианта, мне поможет разобраться как это работает! спасибо!